# INSERT two values into the db from <option>

Tags: php, html, database, pdo

I'm trying to insert 2 values into 2 different columns FROM the `<option>` I have.

Here's my PHP code :

```
$query = "SELECT gid,course_id,course_title,course_cord,group_time,course FROM courses JOIN groups WHERE course_id = course ";
            $run = $connection->prepare($query);
            if(!$run){

              die("rip".mysqli_error($connection));
            }
            $run->execute();
            $run->bind_result($gid,$course_id,$course_title,$course_cord,$group_time,$course);


           while($run->fetch()):



           echo "<option dir='rtl'value='$course_id(the second value is$gide)'>($group_time)$course_title BY $course_cord  </option>";
         endwhile;
```

I'm now inserting `$course_id`. I want to insert `$gid` to the column called group_id which is in students table.

here's my insert query :

```
    $statement = $connection->prepare("
            INSERT INTO students (name_student,certificate_id,specialization,phone_num,date_reg,paid,chair)
            VALUES (:name_student,:certificate_id,:specialization,:phone_num,:date_reg,:paid,:chair)
        ");

        $result = $statement->execute(
            array(
                ':name_student' =>  $_POST["name_student"],
                ':certificate_id'   =>  $_POST["certificate_id"],
                ':specialization'   =>  $_POST["specialization"],
                ':phone_num'    =>  $_POST["phone_num"],
                ':date_reg' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($_POST["date_reg"])),
                ':chair'    =>  "1",
                ':paid' =>  $_POST["paid"]


)
        );
```

The `$course_id` is inserted in certififate_id column.
`$gid` is the id for groups and the groups' table has a course column which I match with a course_id column.

I tried to make a hidden input with `$gid` but it's not what I want :\

How do I Achieve my goal ? I'm very confused about this.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know you can easily get those values using jquery and store them in a variable.
For getting the text value you should use this.
    $( "#myselect option:selected" ).text();
For getting the value tag value you should use this.
    $( "#myselect option:selected" ).val();

Happy Coding